# Botão e Caixa de Texto impedem que o evento KeyPress funcione

Tags: vb.net

Estou a realizar um trabalho em vb.net e se coloco um botão ou uma caixa de texto no form então as teclas que eu defini em KeyPress deixam de realizar a sua função.
Eu gostaria de ter as duas coisas no meu form sera possivel?

Comment: Olá @Rodrigo. Edite a sua questão e coloque o código que está a usar, senão fica difícil ajudar.